# Error Slim Swift 2

Tags: php, ios, swift2, xcode, slim

Tengo una aplicación iOS nativa, en la cual debo consumir un servicio web en donde envío una foto en base 64 al backend en php con framework slim pero me retorna el siguiente error sobre el código 64 de la imagen:

`recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 233 extraneous bytes before marker 0x10`

Este es el código de la conversion a base64 sera que tengo algún error:

```
let img : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgLugar.image!, 1)!
let base64Img = img.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Answer (score 1):

Elimina las opciones al pasarlo a Base64 y seguramente te funcione. En caso de que no, deberías revisar el código del servidor por si está esperando otro formato distinto del que envías.

```
let base64Img = img.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

Comment: Nada no sirvio :'( no el servidor esta esperando un base 64 por dios que hago :'(